# Trying to render multiple sidebars overlaying each other using position fixed but the second sidebar is flickering on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, sidebar

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hello,

I'm trying to create a hamburger menu sidebar in React. When I click the hamburger menu, it opens the primary sidebar with the main routes as expected. Then when I click "Products" which has a dropdown in the main header, it's supposed to replace the primary sidebar (or at least overlay it).
When I move the mouse off the sidebar, it shows the secondary sidebar as expected i.e. img #3, but when I hover over it, it flickers between img #2 and img #3. When I hover over "Products", it shows img #2. I'm using position: fixed for both sidebars. It seems as though the parent (primary) position fixed sidebar is affecting the child (secondary) position fixed sidebar. I thought that position fixed is relative to the document regardless of where an element is in the DOM?

This is a snippet of my React navbar code below:

```
const MainNav = () => {
    const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);
    const notificationContext = useContext(NotificationContext);
    return (
        <nav className={cn(styles.nav, 'container--global')}>
            <Logo />
            <ul className={styles.nav__list}>
                <MainNavLinks />
                <MobileMainNavLinks classes={styles.nav__btn} />
                <button
                    className={styles.nav__btn}
                    onClick={() => {
                        notificationContext.showNotification({
                            title: 'Testing notification using search button!',
                            message: "Search doesn't work yet!",
                            status: 'success',
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    <Search
                        fontSize="large"
                        titleAccess="Search Icon Button"
                        aria-label="button"
                    />
                </button>
                <Link href={URL_PRODUCTS_CART}>
                    <a>
                        <button
                            className={styles.nav__btn}
                        >
                            <span className={styles['nav__btn--cart-counter']}>
                                {cartContext.itemCount}
                            </span>
                            <ShoppingCartOutlined
                                fontSize="large"
                                titleAccess="Shopping Cart Icon"
                            />
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

And this is a snippet of my css for the primary sidebar, followed by the secondary (dropdown). I'm using CSS modules if that matters.

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: $size-sm;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba($color-grey, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar--open {
    width: min(33rem, 85%);
}

.dropdown__sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1100;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: $size-sm;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba($color-grey, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown__sidebar--open {
    width: min(66rem, 85%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried using a React Portal to move the components into the main body of the DOM but that didn't work...

After some more checking I decided to comment out my css hover/focus code...and voila...issue fixed *facepalm*

Update: Think the issue was caused by the transform/scale property on position fixed elements, and more specifically because the underlying sidebar was kept in focus as well